# ros::service::waitForService() blocks infinite

Tags: ros, gazebo, rostest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i use `ros::service::call()` to call e.g. gazebo/apply_joint_effort inside a rostest (c++,gtest) the call sometimes fail and sometimes don't fail ?

So i thought, using ros::service::waitForService("gazebo/apply_joint_effort", -1)) to wait for "something" and then use the call() function, but the waitForService() is blocking endless. But when i call the service with the commandline tool "rosservice", the service is available and returns success ?

is waitForService() for another usage?

thanks
flo

Change 1:
Inserting

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread")
rosbuild_add_gtest(test/mytest test/mytest.cpp)
```

into CMakeList.txt file and running then the binary bin/test/mytest the service call returns success, but the service (force) does not get applied to the model in gazebo?

gazebo dies with:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Time is out of dual 32-bit range

Aborted (core dumped)
```

I got ubuntu-12.04-amd64 installed. Someone knows what this error causes?

Also if i use:

```
rosbuild_add_executable()
rosbuild_add_gtest_build_flags()
rosbuild_add_rostest()
```

in my CMakeList.txt file instead the two other options mentioned before, and run rostest mypackage mytest the test is run 3 times in a row after building? Why is that so?  Also the rostest lib cannot call the service, but the test-binary can call the service (but gazebo dies) ?

Is there a way to prevent the test from running after building it with make test?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58464/ros::service::waitforservice()-blocks-infinite/) by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 406 on 2013-03-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2013-03-19**:
the call ros::service::waitForService("/gazebo/apply_joint_effort", -1) blocks also infinite ?

my test is just:

TEST(MyTest, firstTest)
{
ros::Time::init();   //used for waitForService
if(ros::service::waitForService("/gazebo/apply_joint_effort", -1))
EXPECT_EQ(1,2) << "wait for service ok";
}

Are there some other functions i can call to get more info? like what namespace i am in, or something?

thanks
flo

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-19**:
Please do not create answers for discussion or comments. Instead, either edit and append to your original post or use the comment functionality.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-20**:
I think running it is the intended behaviour of make test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are passing -1 for the timeout, which means: wait infinite.
Just pass a real timeout that you want to wait for.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2013-03-18**:
yes i pass -1 because i want to block so long till i get the service. I know that the service is available because i can run rosservice from console "before" and "after" i run the rostest with the awaitForService() call.  The question is more: why is it blocking, but the service is available ?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-19**:
Maybe you did something wrong in the software. You can just call the service to see, if it works in principle.

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2013-03-19**:
like i wrote in my question, it sometimes works and sometimes fails

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-19**:
How are you registering the service client/calling the service? Also ros::service::call?

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2013-03-19**:
what does the <2> and the green check-mark right beside your answer mean ?

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2013-03-19**:
yes i use  (ros::service::call("/gazebo/apply_joint_effort", req, res)

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-19**:
Your call does have a / before gazebo unlike the waitForService. Did you try @Hansg91's suggestion?

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2013-03-19**:
yes i tried it, like i wrote in the answer to Hansg91  :)

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-19**:
If you are using the same string for waiting as for calling then this should work and be consistent.

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2013-03-19**:
if i use the same part of the main() routine of the file fuerte/stacks/ros_control/controller_manager_tests/test/cm_test.cpp it blocks till it prints on console: in run_test
raise RLTestTimeoutException("test max time allotted")

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-03-20**:
@inflo the number to the left of an answer is its vote - you can up- or downvote an answer, if you like/dislike it, using the arrow above/below. The check sign is for accepting an answer and thereby marking your question as answered.